# Restrict user to upload large files

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please find my code below. I'm trying to restrict a user to upload file less than 4 MB but I'm getting the content length of 80 MB when I'm selecting a file of 830 KB. 
This code `flSignature.PostedFile.ContentLength` is not working. Please help.

TIA

```
string uploadMsg = "";
string appPath = Server.MapPath("~");
string parentpath = appPath + "\\app\\Pictures\\";
//To Upload Multiple Files on Single Click 
HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];

    if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        //if (hpf.ContentLength > 4096)
        //{
        //   uploadMsg = "Collective file size is more than 4 MB.";
        //}
        //else
        //{
        if (hfc.AllKeys[i].Contains("flSignature"))
        {
            if (flSignature.PostedFile.ContentLength > 4096)
            { 
                uploadMsg = "Collective file size is more than 4 MB.";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName).ToLower().Contains("xls") || Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName).ToLower().Contains("doc"))
                {
                    showalert("Only Image can be uploaded.");
                }
                else
                {
                    hpf.SaveAs(parentpath + lblUniqueNo.Text + "_signature_" + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
                }
            }
        }
        else if (hfc.AllKeys[i].Contains("flPhoto"))
        {
            if (flPhoto.PostedFile.ContentLength > 4096)
            {
                uploadMsg = "Collective file size is more than 4 MB.";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName).ToLower().Contains("xls") || Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName).ToLower().Contains("doc"))
                {
                    showalert("Only Image can be uploaded.");
                }
                else
                {
                    hpf.SaveAs(parentpath + lblUniqueNo.Text + "_passport_" + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));

                }
            }
        }
        else if (hfc.AllKeys[i].Contains("flIdentDoc"))
        {
            if (flIdentDoc.PostedFile.ContentLength > 4096)
            {
                uploadMsg = "Collective file size is more than 4 MB.";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                hpf.SaveAs(parentpath + lblUniqueNo.Text + "_doc_" + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
            }
        }


        //}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value carried by the [ContentLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.contentlength.aspx) property is expressed in bytes, not kilobytes.

Therefore, when you issue `flSignature.PostedFile.ContentLength > 4096`, you're actually checking if the uploaded file's size is greater than four kilobytes, not four megabytes.

Try something like:

```
if (flSignature.PostedFile.ContentLength > 4096 * 1024)  // 4194304 bytes
{ 
    uploadMsg = "Collective file size is more than 4 MB.";
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`PostedFile.ContentLength` has to work, when you are browsing more size file than you need `maxrequest` length maximum in `web.config` file

Comment: Its not working flSignature.PostedFile.ContentLength code is returning 80 MB i am confused as the file size is just 800 KB